# How to make map rotate instead of my current location marker osmdroid

Tags: android, gps, osmdroid

I'm writing an android app that uses osmdroid. Right now the map displays and my current location marker (the triangle) rotates on top of the map. Instead of this I would like the MAP to rotate and the current location triangle marker to be locked in one position like a typical car GPS. This is my current code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String PROVIDER_NAME = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
public static final GeoPoint SCHOOL = new GeoPoint(33.989820, -81.029123);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
    //mapView.setMapOrientation(0);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);

    MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(getApplicationContext(), mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();

    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    IMapController mapViewController = mapView.getController();
    mapViewController.setZoom(16);
   }

}
```

Any ideas on what needs to be fixed/added?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you want is implemented in OSMNavigator [MapActivity](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMNavigator/src/main/java/com/osmnavigator/MapActivity.java), using: DirectedLocationOverlay, and LocationListener. 
Have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Could you point me to the section that would be useful to me? I skimmed through the code and not sure exactly what would help me since it's so long

Comment: Related objects are: myLocationOverlay, mLocationManager. The activity extends LocationListener. And most of the related code is in onLocationChanged.

Comment: Is there a way to implement what I'm asking in a simple manner? Possibly sample code

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead default MyLocationNewOverlay:

```
class LocationOverlay(map: MapView) : MyLocationNewOverlay(map) {
    override fun drawMyLocation(canvas: Canvas?, pj: Projection?, lastFix: Location?) {
        if (this.isFollowLocationEnabled) rotateMap(lastFix)
        super.drawMyLocation(canvas, pj, lastFix)
    }

    private fun rotateMap(lastFix: Location?) {
        lastFix?.let {
            if (it.speed > 0.2) {
                mMapView.mapOrientation = -it.bearing
            }
        }
    }
}
```